# How i can change the font color of a specfic placholder/text of a document using google drive api?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to change the font color using Google Drive API. I tried different approaches but they didn't work. I also try to change color of variable value before replacing but this also not work.
The code I tried:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);
$new_doc_id = $copyFile->getId();
$new_doc_name = $copyFile->getName();
$documentId = "$new_doc_id";
$documentName = "$new_doc_name";
$replaceRequests = [];

// For Current Date Only
$searchText = '<<Doc1.Initial>>';
$replaceRequests[] = [
    'replaceText' => $searchText,
    'containsText' => [
        'text' => $searchText,
        'matchCase' => false,
    ],
    'textStyle' => [
        'foregroundColor' => [
            'color' => [
                'rgbColor' => [
                    'red' => 1.0,   // Set red component to 1
                    'green' => 0.0, // Set green component to 0
                    'blue' => 0.0,  // Set blue component to 0
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest([
    'requests' => [
        [
            'replaceAllText' => $replaceRequests[0],
        ],
    ],
]);
$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Comment: That's the docs API not the drive API please fix your tags

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the specific behavior when you say, *'it didn't work'*? Does your code run fine but not change your docs file? Or do you get any **error messages**?

Comment: HI 
Thank you for your response please guide me can i change font color of a specific placeholder/text in a document using Google Docs API or Google Drive API?
Thanks

Comment: The situation is that I'm attempting to replicate your setup using the [`documents.batchUpdate` method](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate), specifically with the `replaceAllText` and `updateTextStyle` functions. However, I've run into an error, which you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/Bj2wIcX). This is why I want to know the specifics in your issue. While your syntax for changing font color seems correct, upon reviewing the API documentation, it seems that changing font colors requires a `range` that includes both `startIndex` and `endIndex`.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 specific text is <<Doc1.Initial>>